# ssl cert for https on local network

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

I'm working on a node project to run a local server. No access to the greater internet. For my project it would be very usefull to have access to the `File System Access API`. As it would allow me to read, and reread, the same file many times over. But the API requires a `Secure Context`, which requires https, and a SSL key, and as far as I can tell, a cert.

Looking into SSL certs they appear to require `WHOIS` data that matches up with the website that's trying to be certified. However this would entirly defeat the purpose of keeping it to the local network, and probably restrict it to when a internet connection is available. Not to mention neither my public IP or location will not be consistant nor will I be using a Domain Name.

I also looked into Let's Encrypt, and CertBot, however they seem to require Domain Name(s). As such they're not an option.

While I could just stick with my current method of using an `<input type = "file">` tag and it's surrounding API, having my clients reselect the file everytime it's updated. It would be a definite improvement to have access to the `File System Access API`.

So, having said that. My question is: Is it possible to gain access to the `File System Access API` within a browser using a server which is exclusivly hosted on a local network?

I have a feeling it's not.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used `File System Access API` much but for localhost https you can try something https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert

Comment: This looks very useful, but it appears to be for https testing as it registers a new CA for authenticating domains etc. Unfortunately I need a workaround that requires no changes to the client machine.

Comment: What I can suggest is to use some local remote access through certain ports (highly risky and should be used with care) but something like ngrock. Auto-deploy (build, etc.) is something you can think of next for testing.
But yet this requires installation of ngrock cli (some portable modification). I doubt if it fits your needs, let me know.

Comment: Hi. Just to confirm whether the mentioned tool was actually *ngrok*. There are also other similar tools, like e.g. *localhost.run*. If needed you might want to search for "local https tunneling"